# gamemaker studio draw event to have collision detection/solid

Tags: game-maker

i dont know if this was able at the first time but do any one know how to make an object draw event to be solid or have collision ? i really needed it, cause i'm too lazy to make for example a box sprite, and i have 1 more question. Do you guys know under tale? if you do how do they make the box in the battle system goinng smaller like an animation, if you had the answer please tell me :3, sorry if i had bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was searching for the same thing, and I found that if you use the transform sprite event and a regular square sprite, you can make rectangles by expanding them and set up a Collison system for the object like Undertale.

[image]

Comment: Is there like another way ? Like using code list thing ? Just asking, but thanks for the help its really do helps me :3